# Cassandra: Operation time-out

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql

I am using cassandra node js driver and i am getting following error:

```
error: Database error found %s . On selectAllJobs() call

{ name: 'ResponseError',
  message: 'Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.',
  info: 'Represents an error message from the server',
  code: 4608,
  consistencies: 1,
  received: 0,
  blockFor: 1,
  isDataPresent: 0,
  query: 'SELECT * FROM cron_tasks WHERE type =? AND starts < ? ALLOW FILTERING ;' }
```

This error occurred when i ported to new instance of AWS. Earlier, everything went fine.

**Cassandra version:**

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.12 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

Comment: Perhaps a firewall issue, is the new instance in the same security group as the previous one?

Comment: I have created exact replica of previous instance.

Also, some of my queries are responding back but some don't.

Answer (score 2):

Read_timeout error means that the coordinator of the query does not know whether the request succeeded or failed, so all it can tell the client is that the request timed out.

In your case, it means that the coordinator of the query sent the request internally to the replica but the replica didn't respond in time.

You can [enable query tracing and execute in cqlsh](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2) to understand why it is happening.

You can read more about [how Cassandra deals with replica failure](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure).